# Upgrading Xamarin Forms to .Net Standard 2

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am attempting to convert my Xamarin project to use .net Standard 2.

- I have added the .net standard 2 library
- I have installed all the nuget packages that previously existed in my pcl library. (all build fine)
- Then I removed the pcl and added the std library

However when I build I get a few compile time exceptions:

- Could not load assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
- Could not load assembly 'XLabs.Forms, Version=2.0.5782.12218, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Those ddl indeed does not exist in the Android bin folder. If I copy the dlls in manually the build error goes away.

I am not that familiar with the new .net standard stuff to know if these libraries are maybe not being copied over because of incompatibilities.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT**: The nuget packages above is only added to the common std and pcl library not the Android 1. This worked with the pcl version so I assumed similar behavior with the std version. I had to install it into the android version to make it work. Why was necessary in the std and not the pcl?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following NuGet packages to your Xamarin.Android project:

- [`IdentityModel` v1.0.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/1.0.0)
- [`XLabs.Forms` v2.0.5782](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/)

I'm not sure why the PCL implementation worked without these packages in your Xamarin.Android project. Likely, the package creators are using [Bait and Switch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzlIzxu5bXAhVjyFQKHVFbAZsQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flog.paulbetts.org%2Fthe-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick%2F&usg=AOvVaw1ZDjROy17Qa0ALhEXDI2Cj) with the netstandard implementation.